# Hiding parts of form InfoPath2010 button

Tags: 2010, infopath

I am Trying to create a form in InfoPath 2010. I would like it that when a button is selected it hides certain parts of the form. Ideally it will hide tables. I have looked at rules but there seems to be no wway of doing this.

If anyone could be any help I would be most grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

we can hide/show controls in InfoPath form using "Section control". When you want to hide a table, add the table to the a section and add conditional formatting.

[How to hide and show controls on InfoPath pages](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/How-to-hide-and-show-controls-on-InfoPath-pages.aspx)